# pairing each RDD value with all the other values in RDD in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to pair each value in the RDD with all the other values of the same RDD. But I am not able to come up with a proper solution.

RDD : Below Image represents the RDD data with pair as-> (UserId, MovieName::Rating).  [image: image that shows the data of RDD -> (UserId, MovieName::Rating)]

I want to pair the moviename and ratings of each user as below:

from the above image:

> - user 1 rated **Edison Kinetoscopic.. as 10** and **La sortie... as 10**
> - user 2 rated **The Arrival .. as 8**, **Le manoir..  as 7**, **Edison Kinetoscopic.. as 7** etc...

SO, the output should be..

```
**key**: (Edison Kinetoscopic,La sortie des)  
**Value** : (10,10), (7,8)   -> Since user 1 and user two rated these two movies  
**Key**: (The Arrival, Le manoir)  
**value**: (8,7)    -> only user-2 rated these two movies.
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: taking the powerset of movies for each user seems to be expensive. Are you sure you cannot do what you want if you only group by each movie, instead? What is the goal of this (a collaborative-filtering recommender system I presume)?

Comment: @vefthym is right. Computing all pairs is quite an expensive operations.

Comment: @vefthym I understand that the operation is quite an expensive, especially when dealing with large data. But I am using correlation value to recommend the movies. So I think I have to pair the movies and rating pairs of each user.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you're trying to build a recommender system, or compute movie-movie similarity, there are must better ways to do this.

However, to solve your problem, you can do the following:

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(List(
      (1,"Edison", 10),
      (1,"La sortie", 10),
      (2,"The Arrival", 8),
      (2,"Le manoir", 7),
      (2,"Edison", 7),
      (2,"La sortie", 8),
      (2,"Le voyage", 8),
      (2,"The Great", 7)
))

// first group user movies
val pairings = rdd.map{case (user,movie,rating) => (user, List((movie,rating)))}.reduceByKey(_++_)

// then get all pairs for each user
val allPairs = pairings.flatMap{case (user, movieRatings) => (1 until movieRatings.length).flatMap(i => movieRatings.zip(movieRatings drop i))}

// re-structure pairings into format we want
val finalPairing = allPairs.map{case ((m1,r1),(m2,r2)) => m1.compareTo(m2) match {case -1 => ((m1,m2),List((r1,r2))); case _ => ((m2,m1),List((r2,r1)))}}.

// group by pairings
val groupByPair = finalPairing.reduceByKey(_++_)

// look at our pairings
pairings.take(100).foreach(println)
```

the `compareTo` is needed to guarantee that movies appear in the same order in the tuple, and thus can be grouped.

Comment: Unfortunately this solution won't scale.

Comment: I think the solution will scale as well as any solution to the described problem. The breakpoint is of course when two popular movies occur in the dataset, and we get intensive jobs within the map functions. It should run however, it will just be slow.

Comment: Really, I think this problem is perhaps not the right way of tackling another problem. If it is a recommender I would take a look into ALS for example :)

Comment: @BenHorsburgh. you are right, using Collaborative filtering and ALS algorithm is the better way to deal this type of problems when compared to this pairing. Since I am trying to solve the problem using correlation values I need to generate movie and rating pairs. Thanks for the solution